# Two Column Input with Flex Box Model

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an input mechanism using the flex box model. I know it's not supported by all browsers, but that doesn't matter in this case. It really only needs to work on web-kit browsers.

I am trying to build a nice two column layout without needing to use specific widths. I have the flex property set to one on both the label and the input. However, as you can see, when the label element gets long, it messes up the width of the input that is next to it.

I want both label and input to be the same width down the column, but I want them to grow and shrink as the size of the window/device changes.

Is there a way to do this without having to set a `width` on either of the elements?

**Update**

I can set a `max-width` on the label elements to 5% and I basically get the desired effect. However, I'm still wondering if there is a way to do this without setting any width and using purely the flex box?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/zero21xxx/XTa98/) is a working jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you provided doesn't have columns at all, just the appearance that there are columns. Without actual columns you will have to set widths to make these 3 unreleated blocks look they are joined in some way.

You should be using the new CSS3 Flexible Box syntax, which is now 'flex' rather than 'box'. See the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/ With this you can set the elements to have a `<grow>` `<shrink>` `<default width>` of 1 1 50%, so they will grow and shrink at the same rate and will each take up 50% of available width (you can adjust this or make it 60/40 or whatever).

Example JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XTa98/4/

Otherwise, if you want actual columns so that you don't have to set widths, you need to wrap all of the labels in their own "column" div and all of the inputs in their own "column" div.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XTa98/5/

This has actual columns and no widths set, but it does not degrade gracefully anymore since the elements are not in their own rows. To alleviate this you could always provide `text-overflow: ellipses` to truncate the text.

In any case, you have a trade-off. If you want the appearance of columns without actually using columns, you will need to set some type of width. Otherwise, you can use real columns but the elements are no longer joined as rows and you will need to account for the overflow when shrinking the browser width.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to wrap the elements in column divs to avoid setting widths. Just set each label and input to flex:1, and you'll get them dividing up the width equally. However, this is effectively just the same as setting each to be 50% wide, in this case, so I'm not sure what advantage it really has.